# 'Change url > refresh' instead of 'refresh > change url'

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I know the title sounds a bit weird, but I didn't know how else to explain this is 1 sentence.*

Basically when I press f5 to refresh (or click on the refresh button on the url bar) I want the following to happen: `Change url> refresh` instead of `refresh > change url` what it does my code right now

The problem of that is that i'm using a php mail form that puts `?resp=..` in my url bar and if that is the case my

---

**My code:**

```
 if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
     window.location.replace("index.php#home");
 }
```

The problem of that is that i'm using a php mail form that puts `?resp=..` in my url bar and when I reload with `?resp=` in my code my javascript will open a modal with this code:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['resp'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $("#myBtn").click(); </script>';
    }
?>
```

A possible other solution is maybe putting `&& performance.navigation.type != 1` in that if statement but that didn't work.

---

So I am looking for 1 of those things:

- `Change url> refresh` instead of `refresh > change url`
- Or add something to the if statement that makes the modal not open if its on a refresh

Comment: What about window.onbeforeunload? (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

Comment: @Sem that's actually exactly what I was looking for ty :)